# How to calculate frequency response of the system? and find missing values

Tags: control-engineering, systems-engineering, frequency-response

I can convert the H(s) into the frequency response which is:

() = (/(1+ ))

and the output in the steady state is:
() = |(2)|sin(2 + ⟨(2))

The phase: ⟨(2), has to equal /4, but how do I find  and ?

[image]

Comment: copy of [this question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/39345/steady-state-error-to-sinusoidal-inputs-output-of-the-system-in-steady-state)

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to help without giving you the solution.

Think about what you know about the relationship

- H(s): transfer function
- X(s): Input
- Y(s): output.

Also, think how X(s) and Y(s) are related to the time domain equivalents x(t), and y(t).

Then consider which quantities you know, and how using the Laplace Transform  (and its inverse) you can get the others.

Eventually you will get to a relationship with  $s, \mu, \tau$ which has to be zero. In order for that to happen the coefficients of $s=j\omega$  should be equal to zero.

**UPDATE**

- $H(s) = \frac{\mu  s}{s \tau +1}$
- $X(s) = \mathcal{L}[u(t)] = \frac{2}{s^2+4}$
- $Y(s) = \mathcal{L}[y(t)] = \frac{5 (s+2)}{s^2+4}$

Note that the angular frequency from u(t) is $\omega =2$.

Since:

$$ Y(s) = H(s) *X(s)$$

$$\frac{5 (s+2)}{s^2+4}=  \frac{\mu  s}{s \tau +1}*\frac{2}{s^2+4}$$

After simple algebraic manipulations, the above equation can be simplified to
$$ 5 s^2 \tau -2 \mu  s+10 s \tau +5 s+10=0$$

By replacing $s$ with $j\omega$, the above equation becomes:

$$ -i \omega  (2 \mu -10 \tau -5) +(10 -5 \tau  \omega ^2)=0$$

For the above equation, in order to be correct for the input frequency of the problem i.e. $\omega = 2 $, both $(2 \mu -10 \tau -5)$ and $(10 -5 \tau  \omega ^2)$ would have to be equal to zero.

From the second (i.e $(10 -5 \tau  \omega ^2)=0$) we obtain $(10 -5 \tau  2 ^2)=0 \Rightarrow \tau=\frac{1}{2}$
$$\tau=\frac{1}{2}$$

Then from the first one (i.e. $(2 \mu -10 \tau -5)=0$), substituting $\tau$

$$2 \mu -10 \frac{1}{2} -5=0$$
$$2 \mu -10=0$$
$$\mu =5$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is the answer to the question above